# Access global variable in Nested function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this nested function. Am trying to pass two global variables but i have scope issue please help. I get this error running it

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')
```

```typescript
mark_paid(id: any) {
    Swal.fire ({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: "You must ensure that you have sent the money first before clicking this button. Providing false information or coinlocking will cause your account to be banned",
      icon: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#7367F0',
      cancelButtonColor: '#E42728',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, ive sent it',
      customClass: {
        confirmButton: 'btn btn-primary',
        cancelButton: 'btn btn-danger ml-1'
      }
    }).then(function(result){
      if (result.value) {

     

        const headerDict = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json',
          token:this.user.token,//Im trying to access this global variable
          username: this.token.username
        }

        const requestOptions = {
          headers: new Headers(headerDict),
        };

        return fetch('https://some.endponint.com/markPaid/'+id,requestOptions)
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (!response.ok) {

              throw new Error(response.statusText);
            }else{

              Swal.fire({
                title: 'Trade Marked as Paid',
                text: 'The seller will check on your payment and send the BTC shortly',
                icon: 'success',
                customClass: {
                  confirmButton: 'btn btn-success'
                }
              });
             location.reload();
            }
            return response.json();
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            Swal.fire({
              title: 'Ops',
              text: 'An error happened please try again',
              icon: 'error',
              customClass: {
                confirmButton: 'btn btn-success'
              }
            });
          });

      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: You should add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which also shows where/how you assign the `user` variable. You say it is a global variable, but you use `this.user`  which indicates, that it is a class-property

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `user` is a global variable at the start of the function save the current reference scope:

```
mark_paid(id: any) {
    let user = user;
    Swal.fire ({
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your 'this.user' has token value and not null. Please check your assign value of 'this.user'. Error cause due to 'this.user' which is lack of value.